# How can I change a checkbox for a radio button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I change a checkbox for a radio button using jQuery?

Comment: It's certainly possible. What do you need it for, in what kind of a scenario?

Comment: I have a radio button and I need that if the value is oone of them, 5 checkbox get transformed in 5 radio buttons and vice-versa, I hope you understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var checkbox = $("#myCheckbox");
checkbox.replaceWith('<input type="radio" name="'+checkbox.attr('name')+'" value="'+checkbox.attr('value')+'" />');
```

Or with jQuery 1.4

```
var checkbox = $("#myCheckbox");
$("<input>",{
    type:'radio',
    name: checkbox.attr('name'),
    value: checkbox.attr('value')
}).replace(checkbox);
```

You change change the type attribute because it causes problems in IE.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to type :)

Comment: I don't know if that did work at jQuery 1.4, but it doesn't at 1.6.  Instead use:
`var checkbox = $("#myCheckbox");
checkbox.replaceWith($("<input>",{
    type:'radio',
    name: checkbox.attr('name'),
    value: checkbox.attr('value')
}));`

Answer (score 4):

given:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change">
<label for="changem">Change Buttons</label><br><br>
<div id="btngroup">
<span><input type="radio" name="btngroup" id="btn-1"></span>
<label for="btn-1">Button 1</label><br>
<span><input type="radio" name="btngroup" id="btn-2"></span>
<label for="btn-2">Button 2</label><br>
<span><input type="radio" name="btngroup" id="btn-3"></span>
<label for="btn-3">Button 3</label><br>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change').click(function() {
    if( $('#change:checked').length > 0 ) {
      var myType = "checkbox";
    }  else {
      var myType = "radio";
    }
     $("#btngroup span").each(function(i) {
     $(this).html('<input type="' + myType + '" name="btngroup" id="btn-' + (i+1) + '">');
    });
  });
});
```

​
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iqeka/)

Answer (score 2):

i think you can't change the type attribute.

as an alternative, you can use divs: one for the checkboxes and other for the radios. and use the `show()` / `hide()` methods...